# How to make the camera not pass through the walls?

Tags: javascript, three.js

My code is based on this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock

---

In the render method I cast rays in four directions from the camera position

```
this.rays = [
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1),
]

...

for (let i = 0; i < this.rays.length; i += 1) {

  this.raycaster.ray.origin.copy(this.camera.position)
  this.raycaster.ray.direction.copy(this.rays[i])
  const collisions = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.room)
  
  if(!collisions.length) continue;

  const stop = collisions[0].distance < 20
    
  if(stop) {

    // ???

  }

}
```

but I can't figure out what to do next. Could you guys help?

---

Here is a working example but pointer lock is not allowed here

```js
class Test {

  constructor() {

    this.size = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    })
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 2000)
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene()

    this.room = null
    this.createWorld()

    this.controls = null
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    this.direction = new THREE.Vector3()
    this.activeMoveDirections = {
      forward: false,
      backward: false,
      left: false,
      right: false
    }

    this.rays = [
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1),
    ]

    this.clock = new THREE.Clock()
    this.clock.autoStart = true

    this.createControls()

    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render)
    addEventListener('resize', this.resize)
    this.resize()

  }


  createWorld() {

    this.createRoom()

  }


  createRoom() {

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000)
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: 'tomato',
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
    this.room = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
    this.room.position.y = 350
    this.scene.add(this.room)

    this.light = new THREE.PointLight()
    this.light.position.y = 400

    this.scene.add(this.light)

  }


  createControls() {

    this.controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(this.camera, document.body)

    const lock = () => {
      this.controls.lock();
      addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown)
      addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup)
    }

    const unlock = () => {
      removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown)
      removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup)
    }

    addEventListener('click', lock)
    this.controls.addEventListener('unlock', unlock)

    const handleKeydown = event => {

      if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'w') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.forward = true
      } else if (event.key === 'ArrowBottom' || event.key === 's') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.backward = true
      }

      if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'a') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.left = true
      } else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'd') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.right = true
      }

    }

    const handleKeyup = event => {

      if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'w') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.forward = false
      } else if (event.key === 'ArrowBottom' || event.key === 's') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.backward = false
      }


      if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'a') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.left = false
      }


      if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'd') {
        this.activeMoveDirections.right = false
      }

    }

  }


  resize = () => {

    this.renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight)
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(devicePixelRatio, 2))
    this.camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

  }


  render = (t) => {

    requestAnimationFrame(this.render)

    if (this.controls.isLocked) {

      const delta = this.clock.getDelta()

      this.direction.z = Number(this.activeMoveDirections.forward) - Number(this.activeMoveDirections.backward)
      this.direction.x = Number(this.activeMoveDirections.right) - Number(this.activeMoveDirections.left)
      this.direction.normalize()


      for (let i = 0; i < this.rays.length; i += 1) {

        this.raycaster.ray.origin.copy(this.camera.position)
        this.raycaster.ray.direction.copy(this.rays[i])
        const collisions = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.room)

        if (!collisions.length) continue;
        const stop = collisions[0].distance < 20

        if (stop) {
          // ???
        }

      }


      this.controls.moveForward(this.direction.z * delta * 500)
      this.controls.moveRight(this.direction.x * delta * 500)

    }

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)

  }

}


new Test()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.136.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.136.0/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js"></script>
```

---

Full working example

https://codepen.io/xforhu/pen/oNGmOPr?editors=0010

Comment: You may try to create a new temporary `x,y,z` position based on the desired position. This is the current camera position PLUS the desired direction. Don't move the camera there right away. First you check with your raycast method if that new position has collision (or collision distance < 20). If not, you move the camera to that position. If yes, then you keep the camera where it is currently.

Comment: @Kokodoko thank you. I think it works now https://codepen.io/xforhu/pen/oNGmOPr?editors=0010